# Is it possible to get generator value twice?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, firebird, bde, firebird1.5

We have run into a very embarrassing problem. It seems that some network or server error lead the front-end application to get a generator value twice.

Is it possible that getting (and updating) the generator value stays in memory, and in case of loss of power, it <strike>remains in memory</strike> doesn't get to be written on disk, so when the power restores, it loses it's current value, so we can get the generator value again?

We are using Firebird 1.5.6, Delphi (BDE and native IBExpert components).

Thanks, 
SanTa

Update 1: It turned out that the server is some linux, if it helps ...

Comment: There is no way to stay in memory **without** power ;o) but maybe you have a hard disc cache controller without backup battery and you have some data lost that has to be written on disc

Comment: Yep, you're right.  I meant if a generator change is only in memory, then in case of power loss, it can not be written to disk, so it phisically disappear, and on disk, there is the old generator value. My question was if it is possible, and if it is, then what can we do to prevent this. Maybe forced write on the database?

Comment: No, this is not possible. The contents of RAM are lost when power is lost; unless it was physically written to the database (disk), it's not available any longer when power is restored.

Comment: Is the problem that you get the same value twice, or that you want to get the same value twice, but don't know how?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: the problem is that we are getting the same value twice (without having gen_id(G_VALUE, 0))

Comment: Twice during same session, or twice after server/client reboot ?

Comment: @Arioch'The In fact, the server is one of our clients', so we don't really know, what happens, but by the server log, we can see that at a specific time of the day (mostly in the evening) clients lose connection to the server, and then, when the client program tries to get the new generator value, it gets the same value again.

Comment: @Arioch'The No, we don't use this method at all.

Comment: Is the generator value the only thing that has an old value, or are other things missing as well?

Answer (score 5):

Generator values are stored on special dedicated pages inside the database. Updates are atomic and occur outside of normal transaction control and should be stored immediately. However when generators keep changing frequently it looks for OS/RAID/HDD as a "hot" page, constantly written and never read. So they have a lot of incentive to keep in cached in memory and little to actually flush it into the media.

If you wanted speed at all costs, disabled FORCED WRITES - or - enabled WRITE CACHE in Device Manager for the drive - or - just chanced to have a RAID Controller that trades speed for safety to get good magazine reviews: then it is quite possible that those header pages did not got saved to HDD before the crash.

Read links mentioned in the answer for https://serverfault.com/questions/279571/lvm-dangers-and-caveats : even if FB thinks the data is saved, even if Windows thinks so - it may simply be untrue. Also read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/16/10411267.aspx

---

Or maybe you have an error in the program including PSQL.
Like

```
i := GEN_ID (Name, 0);
i := GEN_ID (Name, 1);
```

or

```
i := GEN_ID (Name, +1);
i := GEN_ID (Name, -1);
```

---

Or you may have bad options in backup-restore loop, that do reset generator values.

---

I also suggest you reading all the Release Notes of Firebird 2.0 to 3.0 Alpha - if there are mentioned any generator-related bugs, there are big chances you have them in your obsolete 1.5.6

Comment: BTW On Windows Server the write cache is disabled by default and option also is disabled for the disc containing the Active Directory, to prevent this data loss.

Comment: @SirRufo yes, yes, but there is no human-proof technology, yet ;-) And even if Windows is configured okay, there may be weak chain anywhere else as well. Including HDD internal firmware.

Comment: Yes, it is just to prevent and not a "will never ever happen" :o)

Comment: Don't you get "in touch" with ungrounded UPS though :-D

Comment: Generators are not stored on the first page (which is the header page, type `0x01`, but on generators pages, [type `0x09`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/fbint-page-9.html)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel so how should i word it ? top pages, starting pages ? i am not good with adjectives. The point is though, that since this page keeps changing constantly, OS/RAID/HDD has a lot of reasons to cache it forever and not flush it ever :-(

Comment: Technically generator pages can occur anywhere in a Firebird database. If you are really interested, you can look at http://www.ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/design but that requires a bit of 'connecting the dots'. Maybe you can say something like "Generator values are stored on special pages inside the database. Updates are atomic and occur outside of normal transaction control and should be stored immediately."

Comment: Some other applications I've seen it do a MAX() on the field of the generator's used column to update the generator's value.  It is more of a sanity/check to ensure the app doesnt create an ID for a preexisting record.

Comment: NO! those applcations that use MAX should be reworked or removed!!!! that is a best way to screw your database. GEN_ID is the only safe way to update generator except for a single-transaction monopolic access liek when restoring GBK->FDB. In all the rest ways updating generators against MAX is a sure way to destory the database. If you have such applications in production - then de-fang them and disable those statements ASAP!!!

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you are connecting to the database without using aliaes and using paths that are different.  Firebird then thinks that they are two separate databases.  And one set of memory cache knows nothing about another.

This can cause severe database corruptions so it is important to ensure that all access to a database uses the same path.  Or use aliases.